# ASP.NET is it possible to add an attribute that doesn't allow special characters in a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have been scavenging google and looking for a way that I can add regular expressions or some sort of attribute to a string that would show an error message if the user tries to submit the form while special characters are in said string? (similar to the required attribute)

Ex:

```
Allowed -> Username
Not Allowed -> User'Name,&
```

C# Class:

```
  public partial class Client
    {
        public int CID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="This field is Required")]
        public string Company { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
        public string Location { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
        [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
        [Compare("Password")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        [DisplayName("Special Client")]
        public Nullable<bool> Special { get; set; }

        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The value must be greater than 0")]
        [DisplayName("Monthly Purchased Hours")]
        public int HoursPayed { get; set; }

        public string LoginErrorMessage { get; set; }
```

Haven't found anything useful so far so any tips or helpful comments on what to try would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [RegularExpressionAttribute class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to restrict what is allowed and is not with regular expression.

Comment: @Rolthar by default it works with unobtrusive validation. It is as easy as RequiredAttribute usage. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks again! Got it working like a charm :)               
     [RegularExpression(@"[^\`|\~|\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\+|\=|\[|\{|\]|\}|\||\\|\'|\<|\,|\.|\>|\?|\/|\;|\:]+", ErrorMessage = "Special Characters in Company Name not Allowed!")]